# Jquery - Form data in submit function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a large number of dynamically generated elements. in the submit handler I would like to get all the data at once rather than going by each id. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your question is not very clear but maybe you're looking for `serialize()` or `serializeArray()` jQuery methods

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

e.g

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types:

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
var yourFormData = $('#yourFormId').serialize()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('your-form-selector').submit(function() {
    var yourKeyMap = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
});
```